# Can i use a separate machine as an android device to test my android studio APKs?

Tags: stock-android, android-emulator, android-device-manager

I have my main computer in which i have android studio installed and i have an old computer (intel atom processor 32 bit and virtualization not supported). I want to install android in it to test my android studio output apk. Is that possible ?

Comment: Here's some personal experience: Android-x86 (and solutions based on it, e.g. RemixOS) runs just fine on Atoms, but 1) CPU- and storage-intense actions will be slow, 2) you can't just connect the PC to another PC like you do for an Android phone, instead USB sticks are required for file transfer.

Comment: Usually for testing you should us hardware that is similar to the hardware the app will run on. An Atom PC e.g. usually does not have touch support and also the sensors are different.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Remix OS for PC http://www.jide.com/remixos-for-pc

> Remix OS for PC allows you to run our PC optimized version of Android
>   on any computer. Through a simple and quick setup process, enjoy
>   millions of Android apps and games on your PC alongside the many
>   intuitive and amazing PC features we’ve engineered into Remix OS.